# The largest Tuesday number

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

A Tuesday number is a positive integer $N$ with $d$ digits where the given properties hold true for every positive integer $i$ in the range $0<i<d$

- $N\times i$ contains the exact same digits (in any order) as $N$
- Moreover, it should be possible to split $N$ into two parts, such that writing the first half after the second does, in fact, give the value of $N\times i$

Some valid examples of splitting and reordering:

$1371\rightarrow 3711, 7113, 1137, 1371$

$02684\rightarrow 26840, 68402, 84026, 40268, 02684$

**Find the largest Tuesday number.**

Hint

> You probably will require the number to start with a zero.

Comment: the largest one I can think of immediately is 99

Comment: @Novarg The answer is *much* larger than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some extremely large Tuesday numbers, with billions of digits. Probably there is no bound on how large they can get, though nobody knows how to prove this.

If $n$ is a positive integer, the decimal expansion of $1/n$ is eventually periodic, and the period has at most $n-1$ digits. The period can be exactly $n-1$ digits only if $n$ is a prime number (though this does not happen for every prime). For example,
$$
\frac{1}{7}=0.\overline{142857}
$$
has period $7-1=6$ (and indeed $7$ is prime).
 If the decimal expansion of $1/p$ has period $p-1$, we call $p$ a [*full reptend prime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_reptend_prime).

We can obtain a Tuesday number (also called a [cyclic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number)) from one full period of the decimal expansion of the reciprocal of a full reptend prime, and every Tuesday number arises this way. For example, $7$ is a full reptend prime, so $142857$ is a Tuesday number:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
1\cdot142857=142857,&2\cdot 142857=2857\>14,\\
 3\cdot 142857=42857\>1,&4\cdot 142857=57\>1428,\\
 5\cdot 142857=7\>14285,& 6\cdot 142857=857\>142.\\
\end{array}
$$

It can be proven that $p$ is a reptend prime if and only if the first $p-1$ powers of $10$ give distinct remainders when divided by $p$ (in this case one says $10$ *is a primitive root modulo $p$*). [Artin's conjecture on primitive roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) asserts that every non-square positive integer is a primitive root modulo $p$ for infinitely many primes $p$, and this would imply that there exist arbitrarily large Tuesday numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The largest Tuesday number is...

> unknown. It has been conjectured that there are an infinite number, but not proven. ([source](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicNumber.html))

Comment: Although I agree that these must be cyclic numbers. It is not clear to me from that link that there are infinite of them. In other words: Is it known whether there is a largest full reptend prime? If it can be proved that there are infinite you should provide it I think

Comment: @IvoBeckers It appears to be [an open conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin's_conjecture_on_primitive_roots): *"In fact, there is no single value of a for which Artin's conjecture is proved."*

Comment: It does make me wonder the OP's hint. The hint suggests that the solution actually is not a cyclic number because a number with a leading zero can't be cyclic by the usual definition of cyclic I think

Comment: @f" What is Artin's conjecture and what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: @IvoBeckers The solution I read in a book was 0526315789473684210. I myself had no idea that there were larger ones.

Comment: @ghost I think you typed the number wrong above.  It shouldn't have a trailing $0$.  (At least, when I multiply $052631578947368421$ by each of the digits from 2 to 18, it meets the criteria above, while your number doesn't.)

Comment: Notice a number may be cyclic without being Tuesday. Tuesday is a stronger requirement.

Comment: @Fim: How so? Can you give an example of a cyclic non-Tuesday number?

Comment: The splitting condition is not in the description of cyclic numbers. Also the value of $i$ in the description.

Comment: @Fim: The splitting condition is equivalent to being cyclic. Can you give an example of a cyclic non-Tuesday number?

Comment: I did not look for examples, I merely compared the definitions according to the link you provided. It might be that they coincide but I did not give it much thought.

Answer (score 2):

If leading zeroes were not allowed, then:

> For numbers where $d$ is greater than 11,  $N*i$ will have more digits in it than N for the largest value of $i$. The largest cyclic number without a leading zero shown on the Wikipedia page that satisfies the rules of a Tuesday number appears to be **142857**. I don't believe there is a higher one as 7 is the largest prime below 10 and 11 doesn't generate a cyclic number.

Comment: This would be correct if leading zeroes weren't allowed.

Comment: @Zandar Yes, I've realised that now, but I can't delete my answer from my phone!

Comment: @GordonK Leave it undeleted, just add that this would be correct if leading zeroes were disallowed.

Comment: This answer proves that the accepted answer can't be right! So the OP's solution is probably the right one

Comment: @Ivo No, the OP's solution was 052631578947368421, which is also too long - it relies on a leading zero.

Comment: Nevermind. I do believe the accepted answer is right. I was under the assumption that cyclic numbers don't have leading zeroes